# Error in selecting value on mvc dropdown by text in jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I m using this method to select a value on mvc dropdown.

```
$("#orgCreate #country option:contains(Sri Lanka)").attr('selected', 'selected');
```

First time this is ok. But when I try again. Its not select correct value. Is there is a method to deselect  or how can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use ,

```
$("#country option:contains(Sri Lanka)").prop('selected', true);
```